# Creating a separate comments app for a ticket app. Keep getting NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a separate comments app for a ticket app project. How do I get the ticket `pk` from the Ticket model into `get_absolute_url` method that's within my Comment model?

These are my models

ticket models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=MARKED, default=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=PRIORITIES, default='None', max_length=10)
    label = models.CharField(choices=TYPES, default='Misc', max_length=100)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ticket-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

comment models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tickets:ticket-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.ticket_id})
```

main urls.py

```
app_name = 'tickets'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include(('tickets.urls', 'tickets'), namespace='tickets')),
    path('', include('tickets.urls')),
    path('', include('comments.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

tickets urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TicketListView.as_view(), name='ticket-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserTicketListView.as_view(), name='user-tickets'),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/', TicketDetailView.as_view(), name='ticket-detail'),
    path('tickets/new/', TicketCreateView.as_view(), name='ticket-create'),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/update/', TicketUpdateView.as_view(), name='ticket-update'),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/delete/', TicketDeleteView.as_view(), name='ticket-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='tickets-about'),
]
```

comments urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/', CommentListView.as_view(), name='ticket-detail'),
    path('tickets/<int:pk>/comments/new/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),
    path('tickets/comments/<int:pk>/update/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment-update'),
    path('tickets/comments/<int:pk>/delete/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Comment(models.Model):
     ticket = models.ForeignKey(
         Ticket, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
     )
     title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     content = models.TextField()
     date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
 
     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return self.ticket.get_absolute_url()
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion. Says that the `ImproperlyConfigured at /tickets/2/comments/new/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.`

Comment: Can you send the contents of the urls.py file?

Comment: Edited for you.